# Deployment to Ethereum Ropsten test net fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, ethereum, nft

I am trying the freecodecamp project here:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-an-nft/

I am stuck with the step

```
node ./scripts/deploy.js
```

But it fails to deploy to the Ropsten test network.
I am a beginner with NFT and Ethereum and I am not sure how to debug that.

The error message is now that the funds are insufficient.
but I got now more than 10 Ethereum in the Metamask wallet.

```
Error: insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost (error={"name":"ProviderError","code":-32000,"_isProviderError":true}, method="sendTransaction", transaction=undefined, code=INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS, version=providers/5.5.0)
```

How can I find out how much Ethereum I would need ?
I expect it to be sufficient but not sure of course.
And what can be the real reason for the failure ?

Here the deploy script:

```
// ethereum/scripts/deploy.js

async function main() {
  const EmotionalShapes = await ethers.getContractFactory("EmotionalShapes");
  const emotionalShapes = await EmotionalShapes.deploy();

  console.log("EmotionalShapes deployed:", emotionalShapes.address);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Comment: what network are you trying to deploy?, can you show the config?, the problem could be that you are using the hardhat account and not your account

Comment: It is supposed to deploy to the Ropsten Ethereum test network.
I deployed the project so far at gitlab: https://gitlab.com/networkinss/samplenft
Which config exactly do you mean ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Nope, since then it is in waiting status.
Would be good to know how high the value is supposed to be.